# Does the uncertainity principle actually attack determinism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-interpretations, determinism

It's not really clear to me how does QM attacks determinism. It sure attacks *computability*, which is a component of newtonian, naive determinism, but it's often claimed to destroy determinism itself (which says that we can't compute events, but they are determined anyway).

A photon is both a particle and a wave; a particle doesn't have both speed and momentum defined values at the same time; some things are not a in a state, but in a superposition, until they are measured. It's cool, I get it. But aren't there a lot of macroscopical objects that can be described this way as well? A just published book is both a best-seller and a failure, until enough people buy it. It would be impossible to compute which state it is until the state itself 'happens'.

I'm not sure I'm just referring to hidden variables. Where is the problem with observation exactly? It is obvious that the fact that a scientist decides to observe the particle as a wave is due to the fact that he's doing that experiment. And he's doing that experiment because he likes science, because it's written in his DNA or in his education. He's working because he needs to eat, because chemistry of his body tells him so, and so on.

The impossibility to compute in advance which state is correct is due to the free will of the observer, in the exact same way in which the book is a best-seller or not (the decision of people to buy it). But it's just because it's too difficult to know everything: a God-like creature could perfectly know how many people would buy the book and also if the scientist decides to measure the photon as particle or as a wave at a given time.

Is this just superdeterminism? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdeterminism)
Looks like a pretty logical observation to me. What I am missing?

Comment: Note that "best-seller" is not just a human definition. Every time someone buys the book, I write a "1" on a text file on my computer. So, the physical state of my hard drive is in a superposition.

Comment: 1)  "A photon is both a particle and a wave".  False.  2)  "Some things are not in a state."  False.  3)  "A scientist decides to observe the particle as a wave".  Huh?  4)  "The impossibility to compute in advance which state is correct...".  Quantum mechanics puts no limits on our ability to compute, or to know, the state of anything.

Comment: What you are missing is that physics, and quantum mechanics, are extremely useful and precise ways to describe the world. The fact that you don't like what you _think_ the theory is about is entirely your problem, not physics.

Comment: @WillO I'm sorry for the errors. Why is it the Copenhagen interpretation known to be not deterministic?

Comment: Not about the free will of the observer. The mathematics / physics definition of determinism applies here.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_system  Yes the basis of the uncertainty principle includes randomness.  What it does is calculate a bound to the randomness.

Comment: @JonCuster, I'm referring to the fact that QM is classicly known to be not-deterministic (and even thought in schools like that). It's not a question about physics, that's for sure. Am I wrong about the idea that QM is usually referred at like a proof that the world is not deterministic?

Comment: @Frisbee so it's just about computability, and not determinism itself? I'm pretty sure that the Copenhagen interpretation says that some things are intrinsically not predetermined, and not due to a human limit. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Stackexchange is not meant to be a discussion board.  That is all I have to contribute to the stated question.

Comment: @user2502368 - for being so non-deterministic, it can certainly determine things very precisely (oddly enough). You are caught up in philosophy, not science. What a wave function 'means' has little to do with what you can do with it.

Comment: Might be just me, but a lot of this reads as [flame-bait](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flame%20bait).

Comment: @KyleKanos and Frisbee: you can actually look at the "related questions" on the right to see that there are a lot of similar questions on this very site. Saying that a theory is not deterministic doesn't mean to say that it can't predict things correctly. It's an interpretation problem about reality, a very important problem that I can only address if I know enough about the subject. The question is not about physics itself, but I can't talk about the problem if I don't know enough about physics. Gennaro Tedesco answered correctly.

Comment: @user2502368: I'm well aware of what previous questions have asked on this site and I'm rather indifferent on the whole argument (I kinda view it as a complete waste of time, but so is horseshoes and other people still play that). My point is that, to me at least, the *way* you've written your question seems to be invoking an argument and not an answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos I actually think that the discussion we are having right now is a waste of time, including your first comment. Knowing if my post was a flame bait is actually less important than knowing if QM proves that we live in a not deterministic reality. But as you can see, people like to ask question or make comments about things that other people don't consider to be important. The conclusive "What I am missing?" had the intention to imply that something about what I wrote was wrong (I knew it was - I was asking what) and to make the post sound less rude. I'm sorry if it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A photon is both a particle and a wave

is utterly incorrect. A photon is the carrier of the electromagnetic interaction and does not appear in the description of quantum mechanics until you introduce quantum field theory.

> a particle doesn't have both speed and momentum defined values at the same time

Maybe you mean position and momentum (velocity is very complicated to define). However, a particle does not have position defined at any time *at all* because the position operator in quantum mechanics does not have eigenvalues (unless you introduce dual spaces of distributions). Regarding the momentum, a state may in general be described as a linear superposition of base states each one of which has a determined value for the momentum, i. e. it is a momentum eigenstate. The general feature of quantum mechanics is that, although the initial state can be anything, once a measured is performed the state *becomes* compulsorily one of the aforementioned eigenstates; therefore the measure gives reality to the value. If you perform the same measure again you will most likely find a *different* value, and so on and so forth. Hence there is **no true value** for an observable, rather there is a set of (more or less) precise values where the observable can choose to be amongst. If you proceed for infinite measures you will eventually end up with a distributions of values which is proportional to the absolute value squared of the wave function. In this sense people use the terminology of undeterminism, that it, true values of quantities do not exist at all, they appear as consequence of measurement processes. If no measurement occurs, then no value exist at all.

On a different foot is the point of different variables which cannot be measured together. This happens because they are described by mutually non-commuting operators which do not have a set of common eigenvectors; namely, each value of the former operator corresponds to not one but a linear combination of many of the latter. From the experimental point of view this is a consequence of the fact that the first physical quantity needs the aThat is true.pplicaton of the second to be determined and whenever you act with a physical quantity on a system by definition you change its original value.

> But aren't there a lot of macroscopical objects that can be described this way as well?

Quantum mechanics differs from Newton's physics whenever dimensions of the objects are of order of $\hbar$. The macroscopical limit of quantum mechanics can be proven to exactly be Newton's mechanics and the equations for the expectation values of the observables coincide with the classical ones (and so is for the scattering amplitudes in collision processes).

> It would be impossible to compute which state it is until the state itself 'happens'.

Until it is *measured*.

> scientist decides to observe the particle as a wave

Again, a particle is **not** a wave and even if it were the observer does not decide the nature of the things they want to observe. The problem with the observation is not of experimental nature, rather it is in the way quantities are defined to exist (see above).

> The impossibility to compute in advance which state is correct is due to the free will of the observer,

False. The impossibility to compute in advance which state the system is in is due to the fact that there is, by definition, **no a priori** value of quantities *until* they get measured. It is a theoretical obstruction, not an experimental one.

Comment: That's much more clear now, thank you. So, the absolute impossibility to compute the future state of a system is due to the fact that we don't know the values of the variables involved, because the values DON'T exist until they are measured.

Comment: Yes. Also, measurement process *changes* the state anyway, by definition. Therefore even if they existed, they would change after the process, unless you are in an eigenstate of the observable and measure the observable itself (in this case you do know what the precise value is, but that's a special case).

Comment: In your opinion, can the problem with QM and determinism be summarized like this: "if we do the same exact experiment in the same exact initial condition, we could obtain different results"? And if yes, how can we prove that? Space and time can't be the same at the same time. If I run two experiments (or measures) at the same hour in the same room, the position changes; if I do that in the same position, but after, the time changes. No experiment is exactly like the previous one. I assume that there are no reason to assume that time and space influence the measure?

Comment: Although it is true that experimentally it is very hard to re-create the same initial conditions, the problem of determining outcomes in quantum mechanics is due to the theoretical definitions. The standard experiment to prove its validity is the "double slit experiment": there is plenty of very good questions and explanations on the topic in this very site.